# Variable table name in delete SQL query with PHP's PDO safely

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-delete

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to delete a certain row in a table. I'd like to use the function for a few different tables so when I call the function I would make one of the parameters of the functions the table name. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function delete($conn, $table, $id) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();  

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

One problem I'm having though is that because the $table variable goes straight into the SQL Query, wouldn't my database be under risk of SQL Injection?

As I learnt from one of my other questions, I can't just put :table and add it to the bindParam function, so I don't know how to make this function safe. Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sanitize the table data

You can define an array of whitelisted table names to use in your function:

```
$whitelist = array('table1', 'table2', ...)
```

and then use:

```
$myTable= array_intersect_keys($table, array_flip($whitelist));
```

`$myTable` will now be safe.

Comment: $table isn't an array.  You could use array_search().

Comment: Why is the array_flip function needed in this? Sorry I'm still learning and couldn't find a good answer through google! Does it just remove all the other elements in the array not used?

Comment: He is using `array_flip` to convert the array values into keys for easy lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Table names as metadata are much more restricted than row data - so sanitizing a table name should be much more reliable than sanitizing data. By this I ofcourse mean sanitizing outside of PDO.

What we use quite often is a PHP include, that contains all valid table names as an array definition, so we just look it up - if it is not found, and the file age of the include is more than an hour, we run "SHOW TABLES" and recreate the include, so it's quite automagic.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't currently support dynamic SQL string building, but you could try a whitelist of tables or possibly a MySQL prepared statement with PDO's prepared statements (redundant, I know).

```
$sql = "
PREPARE stmt FROM 
'DELETE FROM @tbl WHERE id = :id';
EXECUTE stmt USING :table;
";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':table', $table);
```

This is untested, but may help.